# How to write dates in Apache POI which would be filtered properly

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a block of code which write data to .xlsx file. I need to write some date in "dd.MM.yy HH:MM" format. All is work properly, but when I try to open result file and test filter work, I got issue with that. Filter perceives dates just like strings, instead of dates, and I can't get filter with year and month.

**Filter which I want (in Russian btw, sorry)**
[Expected filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43cT0.png)

**Filter which I get**
[Current filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYJjf.png)

**Code of cell style**

```
        defaultCellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) workbook.createCellStyle();
        defaultCellStyle.setFont(defaultFont);
        defaultCellStyle.setWrapText(true);
        defaultCellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
        defaultCellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
        defaultCellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
        defaultCellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);

        dateCellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) defaultCellStyle.clone();
        CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        dateCellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd.MM.yy hh:mm"));
        dateCellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
```

**Code of value setting**

```
        if (cellValue instanceof Date) {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy hh:mm");
            Date date = (Date)cellValue;
            cell.setCellValue(dateFormat.format(date));
        }
```

Actually I can't get right filter with any other date formats like standard "dd.MM.yyyy"

*Edited:*
I got my data from prepared statement, and in result date value stored in Timestamp type. maybe it will be useful

*Edited 2:*
I didn't give the code where I set the style to the cell, but I do it. It seemed to me that this does not require a description. Sorry for that. Also I tried to do this without using of DataFormat, but it didn't work

Comment: Don't set the value of the cell using DateFormat, set the cell style. That should give you dates, which can be filtered, formatted as you want them.

Comment: @norie i tried to setValue without DateFormat, just Date, and of course i set the style in further code, just don't mentioned it in question. I added this fact to the question

Comment: In your code `cell.setCellValue(dateFormat.format(date));` sets a string cell value, not a date. So only string filters are available - works as designded.. Set a date cell value and a cell style having date number format. Then date filters will be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the cell style by setting `DataFormat` like below,

**Code**:

```
CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd.MM.yy hh:mm"));
Cell cell = sheet.createRow(3).createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue(new Date());
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

**Output**:

[image]

#### Update:

You need to just convert the `cellValue` to `String`

```
if (cellValue instanceof Date) {
// convert cellValue to String
cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd.MM.yy hh:mm"));
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy hh:mm").parse(cellValue);
cell.setCellValue(date);
  }
```

Comment: Maybe it would work with setValue(new Date()), i don't test it. But in my case with data from database it don't work correct. But my code is otherwise the same as yours, with the exception of "new Date()"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't apply the style..?

```
if (cellValue instanceof Date) {
    cell.setCellValue((Date)cellValue);
    cell.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);
}
```

Comment: I did it in further code, just forgot to add in question

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a date time formatter :

   ```
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("dd.MM.yy HH:MM")
        .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
   ```
2. after that set the date :

   ```
         cell.setCellValue(dateTimeFormatter.format(date));
   ```